# HasFlag for a combination of bitwise and single-value Enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums, keyboard, bit-manipulation

I have three enums, which - **in combination** - should identify a unique state of affairs.

#### A struct of Enums, some bit fields, others not

```
enum KeyCode
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E
}

[Flags]
enum KeyModifiers
{
    Empty = 0,
    NoModifiers = 10000,
    Shift = 20000,
    Control = 40000,
    Alt = 80000
}

enum KeyState
{
    Empty = 0,
    Down = 10000000,
    Up = 20000000
}
```

*I would like to implement a class which encompasses that state, and which would provide a `Contains` method, which would allow me to somehow treat the combination of these enums as a single value supporting bitwise operations.*

But the current implementation does not work, I believe because some of the underlying enums are not bit fields.

#### Contains does not work due to KeyCode

```
class KeyEvent
{

    public KeyEvent(KeyCode key, KeyState down = KeyState.Empty, KeyModifiers modifiers = KeyModifiers.Empty)
    {
        Key = key;
        State = down;
        Modifiers = modifiers;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)Key + (int)State + (int)Modifiers;
        }
    }

    public KeyCode Key { get; set; }

    public KeyState State { get; set; }

    public KeyModifiers Modifiers { get; set; }

    public bool Contains(KeyEvent comparable)
    {
        return (Id & comparable.Id) == comparable.Id;
    }

}
```

*How could I achieve my aim, which is to be able to compare the current values of those enums (`this` `KeyEvent`) with an input set of those enum values (as another `KeyEvent`) so as to determine whether the input values are contained within the current instance (but not necessarily equal to it) ?*

- I could simply compare the enums separately, but is there a better solution?
- I do not want to create a fourth enum that combines all the other three in a bitwise manner, [as KeyData does for KeyCode and modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd2sws4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to either define `KeyCode` like this

```
[Flags]
enum KeyCode {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8,
    E = 16
}
```

Or to calculate the combined value with

```
return (int)Math.Pow(2, (int)Key) + (int)State + (int)Modifiers;
```

Comment: I copy-pasted `2^(int)Key` which is a very neat solution, but it didnt work, probably because you meant `(int)Math.Pow(2, (int)Key) + (int)State + (int)Modifiers;` Unfortunately, that does not work either in my case, because in actual fact i have more than 200 values in `KeyCode` and not even `ulong` or `decimal` has a large enough maximum to accommodate such powers - so i will have to use individual enum comparisons (which is not bad in itself). thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I meant the power. `^` is XOR, `:-(`. And of cause you need one bit per enum value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `KeyCode` isn't a bit-wise field, so using bit-wise logic on it does not make sense. However you can easily take out `KeyCode` and do the rest of the comparison as you have shown.

```
public int StateModifiers { get { return (int)State + (int)Modifiers; } }

public bool Contains(KeyEvent comparable)
{
    return Key == comparable.Key && ((StateModifiers & comparable.StateModifiers) == comparable.StateModifiers);
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats what im kind of doing now, but using the `HasFlag` extension method available in .NET 4